# Closure of given two topologies.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

I am reading topology book and question is some example with closure of a set.The book is not in English so I will define closure of a set how it is defined in my book.

$M_1$ is called closure of  $M\in X$  if it  consists of points that every neighborhood of that points have non-empty intersection with $M$

My book says for ($R$,standard topology) space closure of $(a,b),[a,b),(a,b],[a,b]$ is $[a,b]$

But for ($R$,finite-complement topology) closure of $(a,b),[a,b)$ is $[a,b)$

Can you explain why for first example closure of $(a,b),[a,b)$ is $[a,b]$ but for second example $[a,b)$?

And how it is possible to talk about (a,b) in finite complement topology? Complement of (a,b) is R/(a,b) which is not finite set?

Comment: For the first example (with the standard topology) you certainly can give an answer yourself, using your definition.

Comment: Yes @DietrichBurde because  every neighborhood of $b$ has non empty intersection with $M$ but can't understand why $b$ is not in closure for second example.

Comment: Maybe you mean the lower limit topology (orSorgenfrey topology) on $\Bbb R$. Then the fact is correct. As the answer shows, it’s wrong for the cofinite topology. Are you sure you’re reading it right?

Comment: What's the book? Copy the remark (whatever the language?) Curious...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your book is mistaken (or you have misunderstood it).  In the finite-complement topology (sometimes known as the cofinite topology), the closure in $\Bbb R$ of $(a, b)$ is $\Bbb R$.  That's because every neighborhood of every point in $\Bbb R$ contains all but finitely points of $\Bbb R$, so every open set of $\Bbb R$ has nonempty intersection with any infinite subset of $\Bbb R$, and $(a, b)$ is an infinite subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: If we take $(1,3)$ as $(a,b)$ and take $4$ from $R$ than we can take very small neighborhood of $4$ that has empty intersection with $(1,3)$.I know that I am doing something wrong here can you explain what?

Comment: And @RobertShore how it is possible to talk about $(a,b)$ in finite complement topology? Complement of $(a,b)$ is $R/(a,b)$ which is not finite set?

Comment: @unit1991 It's still a subset of $\Bbb R$.  It's just neither open nor closed in that topology.  You can meaningfully define and talk about the closure of arbitrary subsets.